# msp file through powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, silent-installer, start-process, msp

I am trying to silently install a windows fabric patch file (.msp) with powershell.

I tried this :

```
$argumentCU1 = "/i "+ '"' + $execCU1 +'"' + " /quiet"
Write-Host $argumentCU1
(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $argumentCU1 -wait -verb runas).WaitForExit
```

where $execCU1 is the path to the file (UNC path)
but it does not even launch.

Is it even possible to execute .msp through powershell? Is this cmd line correct?

thank you

Comment: MSP is just a transform file that usually accompanies and MSI file. msiexec.exe /i "pathto .msi file" /p "pathto .msp file"

Comment: So i have to install the msi with his update in the same command?

Comment: Found my error thanks for the informations

Comment: I said usually. Sorry if my comment was misleading... You found the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the .msp files are patches for update i need to use "/update" and not "/i"

because "/i" parameter is for installation (msi) and /update is for the msp files

simple as that...